# Syntax for pointer to multidimensional array inside a struct

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, struct

I have this array

```
const uint8_t pat_blank [2][7]= {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

and this pointer to the array

```
const uint8_t(*patternptr)[7] = pat_blank;
```

that I access like so `patternptr[i][j]`

So far, so good. Stuff works great. Now my problem:

I also have this struct

```
typedef struct lightingparams
{
    const uint8_t (*patternptr)[7];
}
```

I'm trying to create an instance of the struct pointing to the array but I cannot figure out the proper syntax to do it

This didn't work

```
lightingparams newparams = {
    (*.patternptr)[7] = pat_blank;
}
```

I'm also not sure what the proper syntax is to assign a new value to the pointer.

This didn't work

```
(*newparams.patternptr)[7]=pat_blank;
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to include the declarator in the left hand side.  Don't.  For the structure field initialization, just use `.patternptr = pat_blank`.  For the assignment, just use `newparans.patternptr = pat_blank;`

Comment: THAT'S IT??! Much thanks. When I get some time, I should try and learn C more formally.

Comment: "I should try and learn C more formally" hmmm... trying to write C without learning it first, will cost you a lot of wasted time. To save time, learn C then write programs.

Comment: You can also do `lightingparams newparams = { pat_blank };`

Comment: BTW: The `typedef` is incomplete. Seems `lightingparams;` is missing in the end.

Comment: Oh yes. I did leave that out. Thanks